# Objective C - How to create a set of sub views to update

Tags: objective-c, uiview, properties

Perhaps I am thinking about this incorrectly, so please point me in the right direction..

I want to make many UIViews as a property so I can update them with different methods. Something like this:

```
@property UIView *view1

@property UIView *view2
...

@property UIView *view200

-(void)updateViews{

for (i=0; i <200; i++){

//Update view here

}
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I easily make multiple views?
2. How can I easily pass a message to each individual view?

So many great responses, I think I need to add a little more info.

Have tried putting my UIViews into an array to index them but I struggle to access them to update their positions within the UIViewController. I thought making them a property is the correct way to since I need to update them with the device heading. Looks like using a tag might be best. Can someone further comment on this approach:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 144; i++) {
UIView *sunView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sun.png"]];
    sunView.tag = i;
}

//then later, in a separate method do the following:

for (i = 0 ; i < 144; i++) {
CGFloat CGx = self.acceleration.X;
CGFloat CGy = self.acceleration.Y
[sunView.tag.i setFrame:CGRectMake(CGx, CGy, 20, 20)]
}
```

Im not sure how to access the UView with the corresponding indexed tag. Can someone help me there too?

Comment: Quite unclear what you're trying to do, or why you would want to do it that way. Elaborate more. Otherwise you'll just use `[[UIView alloc] init]` and that's it. Pass what message?

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) are these all subviews of a `UIViewController` / `UIView`? - and are you creating them in a normal way, as part of the view hierarchy (that's in response to your 1st question). (2) Do you need to expose them all as properties? Or do you just want a convenient way of updating them all?

Answer (score 1):

Create your views in a loop and store them in an NSMutableArray. That way you will have access to all of them in your view controller.

Create a property.

```
@property (monatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfViews;


self.arrayOfViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIView *view;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.arrayOfViews addObject:view];
}
```

Run a loop over this array and access the views one by one and call the method you need to call.

On a side note: Why are you creating 200 UIViews? That's a lot :)

Comment: I tried using an NSMutableArray but I struggle to access them later. Can you give an example of how to access the view objects?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, does it help now? Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

When they are really subviews then you could iterate through the superview's subviews array.

You could do that recursievely in order to apply it on all subivews of your subviews, if you have multiple hierarchy levels.

If you don't want to apply this to each of your superview's subviews, then tag your subviews with something like `view.tag = 6502` and use that to identify those views to which you want to apply it.

Or maintain your own array or set (iterable collection) of views and iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I easily make multiple views?

Do you want to create it in IB?

**1) You can use tags in Xcode**

[image]

UILabel * label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:19];

UIView * view = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:20];

**2) You can use property that you also do**

> How can I easily pass a message to each individual view?
>   if your views inside another view(currentView) you can use that

```
for (UIView *yourView in self.currentView.subviews) {
    //Update view here
}
```

Or if you want to create it in the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
      UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10*i, 10*i, 25, 25)];
      int r = arc4random() % 255;
      int g = arc4random() % 255;
      int b = arc4random() % 255;
      myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
     [self.view addSubview: myView];
}
```

That's what you can see

[image]

And to call all these views you can use

```
 for (UIView *yourView in self.view.subviews) {
    [yourView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And that's what you'll see

[image]

If you want to call own view you can use tags like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10*i, 10*i, 25, 25)];
         myView.tag = i + 21;
         int r = arc4random() % 255;
         int g = arc4random() % 255;
         int b = arc4random() % 255;
         myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
         [self.view addSubview: myView];
     }

     for (UIView *yourView in self.view.subviews) {
         if (yourView.tag == 21) {
             [yourView removeFromSuperview];
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I think I have better grip on it now.

Comment: @MattyB I am glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
-(void)updateViews
{
    UIView *views;
    UILabel *label;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfViews ; i++)
    {
        views = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,views.frame.size.width,views.frame.size.height)];
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        [views addSubview:label];
        [self.view addSubview:views];
    }
}
```